# importing imports from your imports in python

Tags: python, import

Question: In python, Is it wise to use the imports from your sub classes, or does it matter?

---

Info:

So, I have a program split up over 6 files. in almost every one of the .py files i import threading, socket, and pickle. What I'm wondering is this, is there an efficiency difference between:

File1.py:

```
import socket
```

File2.py:

```
import File1
import socket
```

and this:

File2.py:

```
import File1
from File1 import socket
```

Or even this:

File2.py

```
import File1
socket = File1.socket
```

Comment: yo dawg, we heard you like imports..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `from File1 import socket`. It doesn't make a performance difference, but it gives headaches to other people having to look in the other file to see that `File1.socket` is actually `socket`, and it might get messy if you decide you don't need `socket` in `File1`.

Also, this is against [the python principles](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) because:

1. it's not the obvious way to do it
2. flat is better than nested
3. readability counts
4. special cases aren't special enough to break the rules

Answer (score 2):

The import statement is smart enough to realize when a module has already been imported, an not import it again. So:

File.py:

```
import socket
```

File2.py:

```
import File1
import socket
```

is just fine.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no efficiency difference. The first approach is the best, since it promotes modularity (like for instance, what if File1.py decides to stop importing `socket`, then File2.py gets broken)